# Using a Named Range to identify worksheets to use a SUMIFS on a to add an array of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs, named-ranges, named

Below is a sample of the Google Sheet I'm working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LDsfn_FMdUSfuFZAyuXf5gdlOSN9yLqhT1RY8aX7Nfs/edit?usp=sharing

On the spreadsheet **Team Totals**, I'm trying to calculate all the sales based on the date, the type of sale, and the program type starting from **Row 27**.

The problem I have run into is that the Named Range, **Consultants**, only pulls the data from the first cell of the Named range (*Octo*). What I want is for a formula that will pull the data of the selected range from each entry in the named range and sum them together.

For reference, I put what the proper values should be starting from **Row 33**.

The closest example I have seen was from this website: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/sumif/sumif-across-multiple-sheets

However, I get the same problem that only the first cell in the named range gets pulled.

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I have been bouncing it around my head for hours and can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try using Apps Script? I see that all your sheets have the same pattern, probably it is easier to accomplish the same result with Apps Script.

Comment: I tried a script and didn't like that it was slower and didn't update when the spreadsheet was updated unless I refreshed it. Besides, I now have a working solution. I was hoping to have something a bit more efficient using a named range, but it seems that doesn't exist oddly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trying to figure out a way not to use an iterative process, I folded and did this:

```
=arrayformula(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$B$4&"'!F6:F100"),INDIRECT("'"&$B$4&"'!D6:D100"),$B$2,INDIRECT("'"&$B$4&"'!E6:E100"),E$27,INDIRECT("'"&$B$4&"'!A6:A100"),$A41)+
SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$B$5&"'!F6:F100"),INDIRECT("'"&$B$5&"'!D6:D100"),$B$2,INDIRECT("'"&$B$5&"'!E6:E100"),E$27,INDIRECT("'"&$B$5&"'!A6:A100"),$A41)+
SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$B$6&"'!F6:F100"),INDIRECT("'"&$B$6&"'!D6:D100"),$B$2,INDIRECT("'"&$B$6&"'!E6:E100"),E$27,INDIRECT("'"&$B$6&"'!A6:A100"),$A41)+
SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$B$7&"'!F6:F100"),INDIRECT("'"&$B$7&"'!D6:D100"),$B$2,INDIRECT("'"&$B$7&"'!E6:E100"),E$27,INDIRECT("'"&$B$7&"'!A6:A100"),$A41)+
SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$B$8&"'!F6:F100"),INDIRECT("'"&$B$8&"'!D6:D100"),$B$2,INDIRECT("'"&$B$8&"'!E6:E100"),E$27,INDIRECT("'"&$B$8&"'!A6:A100"),$A41)+
SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$B$9&"'!F6:F100"),INDIRECT("'"&$B$9&"'!D6:D100"),$B$2,INDIRECT("'"&$B$9&"'!E6:E100"),E$27,INDIRECT("'"&$B$9&"'!A6:A100"),$A41))
```

This formula allows me to cut and paste it to various cells easily, and does the job I need it to, while still using the indirect reference so I can change names without breaking the formula (granted I change the worksheet name as well).

I will need to edit this to include all possible worksheet amounts I can forsee, but once it's done, I won't have to tinker with names anymore.

I'm not happy with this answer, as it creates a really long and ugly formula, essentially repeating the same formula 20 times, but it does work. I feel like there should be an easy function that would be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This will return Total sales:

`=if(isna(ArrayFormula(QUERY({Lo!$A$5:$F; Tulio!$A$5:$F;Ya!$A$5:$F; Miguel!$A$5:$F;Kevin!$A$5:$F; Octo!$A$5:$F}, "select sum(Col6) where  Col1=date '"&TEXT(A28,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label sum(Col6) ''",0)))=TRUE,0,ArrayFormula(QUERY({Lo!$A$5:$F; Tulio!$A$5:$F;Ya!$A$5:$F; Miguel!$A$5:$F;Kevin!$A$5:$F; Octo!$A$5:$F}, "select sum(Col6) where  Col1=date '"&TEXT(A28,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label sum(Col6) ''",0)))`

BTW, I get Total sales of $0, $615.50 and $2,498.00

Comment: I'm aware I can do a manual process of individualing referencing each sheet, but it seems like inefficient programming. Also, the results of your equations are incorrect to the actual totals.

I am having a hard time accepting that there isn't a way to use a named range (or just a range) to solve this issue.

The way I see it, this is just iterating the calculation across each cell in the range. I can easily do it to one, so I just want to do that same thing across the whole range. I'm guessing I have to look deeper into Arrays or Matrices to figure out something.

Comment: I was wrong about the totals, my mistake. I figured an alternate way of doing with indirect references that allows for a more dynamic input.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pull data from a lot of unknown tab names without a script is to actually CREATE the tab names beforehand. On your sheet it looks like you're anticipating/making space for 21 employees.  If I were you, I would just create 15 more tabs named Temp7,Temp8,Temp9... etc.  Then you can just "hide" those tabs. Then a formula can be built in your totals section that will easily stack all the tabs up using an array literal and a QUERY( {   }  ) to add up the totals for you without all this INDIRECT() nonsense that you have been going through to pull from the individual tab names.

Would pre-adding tab names be something you were interested in if I could show you the formulas to make the totals easy to calculate?

Comment: The point of the named range was to identify the tab names in an easy to access list. My question is how would I go using the named range to get these totals? Unless you are saying that isn't possible?

Comment: that is correct.  You cannot use the named range to get the total because INDIRECT() cannot be used inside an arrayformula to populate multiple INDIRECT's at once.

Comment: In excel it is possible, but I don't know excel well enough to tell you how to do it.  Google sheets was designed to collect data in ONE place, and then DISaggregate it for analysis with QUERY()s and filters and Vlookups().  Excel was designed to collect data in MANY places and use formulas to AGGregate it in one place.  Fundamentally different in design despite their outward appearance being similar